# Segueing between views in NavigationController is not functioning correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have an app which includes a settings view that has been set up using a UITableView with prototype cells. When populated, each of the cells then leads to a subsequent settings page. These subsequent settings pages should then allow the user to navigate back to the main settings page (and ultimately out of settings back to the main menu).

The underlying mechanics of each settings page *is working correctly* independently. The issue I'm having is tying these all together in a navigation flow.

### FIRST APPROACH

Originally, I had coded the settings screens as a number of different view controllers and created manual segues to each view controller from the main settings screen (and manually created the segues back to the main settings screen). The main settings screen was essentially a visually customize UITableView with prototype cells. This approach worked as intended, but is quite clumsy with the need to manually code each segue on each screen.

### NEW APPROACH (which isn't working)

In order to make things cleaner and easier to manage (code-wise), I have tried to achieve the same effect using a Navigation Controller with my main settings page embedded into the navigation controller (that may not be the correct terminology, but essentially the main settings page is what you see when you enter the storyboard through the navigation controller). From there, I have connected the main settings page to each secondary settings page using segues.

Using the navigation controller approach, the main settings page loads correctly and works correctly (ie: the correct content loads, the table scrolls, the switches work, etc..) but whenever a cell is tapped which should invoke the segue to the secondary settings page, it seems like nothing happens ... however I can see the print lines have run for the selected secondary settings page and the main settings page just freezes and becomes non-functional.

Simple demonstration of the main settings screens leading to the next: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrQGO.png

Segue identifier and details:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIzL9.png

The following code is used in the main settings screen to initiate the segue to the Timer screen (for example). And the segue to the Timer screen has the identifier "ShowTimerView".

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        print("\(indexPath.row) was selected.")

        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            // Action when timer button pressed
            print("Timer button pressed.")
            print("-----Segueing to Timer view.")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowTimerView", sender: nil)
        }
}
```

As described previously, tapping on the timer cell to navigate to the Timer screen results in the main settings screen becoming non-responsive and the Timer screen never appears. I can tell the Timer screen has loaded/run as print lines within the timer page's ViewController run and appear in terminal.

I've tried playing around with all sorts of different things to get it to work. I presume there is a silly error I'm making, as when I change the segue kind from "Show" to "Present Modally" the Timer screen loads and appears... but the navigation bar doesn't load so there is no way to navigate back to the main settings screen.

As an FYI, I do get the following terminal output when navigating to the main settings screen from the main menu... not sure whether it would be of any help in nailing down the issue:

```
Settings button pressed.
-----Segueing to Settings view.
2019-01-20 20:54:58.979042+0000 ThirtySeconds[14618:388866] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001f68690 UILabel:0x7fb2a1d636b0'Settings'.top >= UILayoutGuide:0x600000560fc0'TitleView(0x7fb2a1c62740)'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001f685a0 UILabel:0x7fb2a1d636b0'Settings'.firstBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x600000560fc0'TitleView(0x7fb2a1c62740)'.top + 28   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001f68690 UILabel:0x7fb2a1d636b0'Settings'.top >= UILayoutGuide:0x600000560fc0'TitleView(0x7fb2a1c62740)'.top   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

And then once I press the Timer cell, the following output is appears:

```
Timer button pressed.
-----Segueing to Timer view.
2019-01-20 20:55:38.339771+0000 ThirtySeconds[14618:388866] [Answers] Logging Answers event: <ANSPredefinedEvent: content_view
{
    "content_id" = "N/A";
    "content_name" = Timer;
    "content_type" = "Settings Screen";
}
{
}>
2019-01-20 20:55:38.359086+0000 ThirtySeconds[14618:389499] [Answers] Logging predefined event to Firebase. <select_content
{
    "content_type" = "Settings Screen";
    "item_id" = "N/A";
    "item_name" = Timer;
}>
2019-01-20 20:55:38.365187+0000 ThirtySeconds[14618:388866] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001f6ab20 UILabel:0x7fb2a1d73f60'Timer'.top >= UILayoutGuide:0x600000561ce0'TitleView(0x7fb2a1c110a0)'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001f6a850 UILabel:0x7fb2a1d73f60'Timer'.firstBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x600000561ce0'TitleView(0x7fb2a1c110a0)'.top + 28   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001f6ab20 UILabel:0x7fb2a1d73f60'Timer'.top >= UILayoutGuide:0x600000561ce0'TitleView(0x7fb2a1c110a0)'.top   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: A navigation controller comes with a navigation bar.  Is it possible that this is making your constraints all wonky because they are built without the navigation bar in mind?

But I would take the extra mile and manually load the view controller from the storyboard (maybe even place the VC in its own story board) and do a manual `navigationController.present(vc ...)` method. I'm sure a lot of people would disagree with me but to me segues (and storyboards) are the spawn of satan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Turns out the issue was the height modifications that I had made in the subclassed navigation controller. Removing this modifications results in everything running and behaving as expected.